# Can different types of elves or dragons have children?

Tags: the-dragon-prince

On the show *The Dragon Prince*, we have seen large groups of Earthblood, Sunfire, and Moonshadow elves, all living in their own villages or cities of a single type of elf. However, despite a lack of prejudice and enforced physical segregation, we seemingly haven't seen any relationships between different types of elves (despite there being at least *three* examples of elf-human romances), nor do I recall any elves with ancestry from multiple groups being mentioned.

Similarly, in the case of dragons, we have seen one baby storm dragon, who was the son of two other storm dragons, and a large number of adult dragons.

As such, can different types of elves or different types of dragons produce viable offspring? Or are they effectively different species?